# Periodic Solution of inhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g\in C(\mathbb{R})$ is a nonnegative periodic function $g(t+1)=g(t)$. **Find conditions** on $a,g$ such that the linear inhomogeneous equation $$\dot{x}=ax+g(t)$$ has **a periodic solution**. When is this solution **unique**?

I can also use **Poincare map**

I should use the fact that the solution of the inhomogeneous equation $$\dot{x} = a(t)x +g(t)$$ is given by $$x(t) = x_{0}A(t,t_{0})+\int_{t_{0}}^{t} A(t,s)g(s)ds,$$ where $$A(t,s) = e^{\int_{s}^{t}a(s)ds}$$.+

So my idea was to show that $A(t,s) \neq 0$ but I am not sure if that´s right path at all. I would appreciate if someone could give me a suggestion or help to formulate the solution mathematically correct?

I´ve seen this solution already [Find periodic solution of differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054083/find-periodic-solution-of-differential-equation) but there is no mention of $a$ being a constant and $g$ a periodic function or how does that relate to uniqness.

Comment: How about this:$\frac{d x}{dt}-ax=g(t)$  It's integrating factor is $e^{-at}$, so
$x=e^{at} \int e^{-at} g(t) dt+ Ce^{at}$

Comment: And how from there folows that the solution is period and which are the conditions for a and g in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the periodicity condition into the solution formula
$$
x(t)=e^{at} \int_{t_0}^t e^{-as} g(s) ds+ Ce^{at}
$$
that is,
$$
x(t)=x(t+1)=e^{at+a} \int_{t_0}^{t+1} e^{-as} g(s) ds+ Ce^{at+a}
$$
so that comparing both sides
\begin{align}
C(e^a-1)&=\int_{t_0}^t e^{-as} g(s) ds - e^a\int_{t_0}^{t+1} e^{-as} g(s) ds
\\
&=\int_{t_0}^t e^{-as} g(s) ds-\int_{t_0-1}^{t} e^{-as} g(s+1) ds
\\
&=-\int_{t_0-1}^{t_0} e^{-as} g(s+1) ds
\end{align}
Now the question reduces to the computability of $C$ and its uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me further by explaining how should $a$ and $g$ be explicit conditioned at the end to get the periodic solution?

Comment: Obviously you want $a\ne 0$, and if $a=0$, you have to consider the case that the right side is zero.

Comment: And for function $g$ there are no special conditions but what we already assumed?

Comment: Yes. $g$ gives the numerator, so that there is nothing happening except in the case where you solve $C\cdot 0=0$.